# Where is "See you Space Cowboy" from?

Tags: cowboy-bebop

I feel stupid not knowing, but I can't quite put my finger on where ["See you space cowboy"](http://www.seeyouspacecowboy.com) is from. I know it's from an anime (that I think was made in the 90s?), but what anime specifically is it from?

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that at least half the results on the first page of [a Google search for `see you space cowboy`](https://www.google.com/search?q=see+you+space+cowboy) refer to Cowboy Bebop.

Comment: This post also further elaborates on the famous Cowboy Bebop phrase: [What is the meaning of the phrase at the end of the last Cowboy Bebop episode?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/340/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-phrase-at-the-end-of-the-last-cowboy-bebop-episode)

Comment: If you've got your answer, you should accept one :)

Answer (score 18):

It's definitely Cowboy Bebop.

The background character is Spike Spiegel:

[image: Spike Spiegel, silhouetted]

[image: Spike Spiegel]

The phrase is taken from one of the ending credits:

[image: "SEE YOU SPACE COWBOY..."]

However, the song on that website doesn't match the song entitled ["See you Space Cowboy"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWkHeQy1WRAg) on the Original Soundtrack, but is in fact ["Space Lion"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRxPFRHwjcI).

Comment: Spiegel not Segal

Answer (score 7):

I think it resembles a lot of [Cowboy Bebop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowboy_Bebop).

> Cowboy Bebop (カウボーイビバップ Kaubōi Bibappu?) is a 1998 Japanese anime
>   series developed by Sunrise. It featured a production team led by
>   director Shinichirō Watanabe, screenwriter Keiko Nobumoto, character
>   designer Toshihiro Kawamoto, mechanical designer Kimitoshi Yamane, and
>   composer Yoko Kanno. The twenty-six episodes (sessions) of the series
>   are set in the year 2071. It follows the adventures, misadventures and
>   tragedies of a bounty hunter crew travelling on the Bebop, their
>   starship. Cowboy Bebop explores philosophical concepts including
>   existentialism, existential ennui, loneliness, and the past's
>   influence.

Comment: Crucial information point: At the end of a Cowboy Bebop episodes, there is a black screen, with a subtitle that says "See You Space Cowboy.."

Answer (score 2):

Cowboy Bebop! at the end of every episode it says "See you space Cowboy" then goes to the ending.

Comment: You should try to expand your answer a bit more. We prefer a bit more detailed answers over 1 liners (even if it is correct) Check the answer above by Rikkin for a good sample